# Bootstrap 3 with Flush footer to bottom of page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I've been getting into web development and started to work on my own page. I had one problem that I couldn't solve for a while.

On mobile and normal size computer screens, the footer looks fine.
...But on **larger** computer screens (like 1229x1182), it pops off and leaves a space underneath the footer.

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong? **The website is on my GitHub pages at** http://joroze.com/

I just want it to be always at the bottom of the content and also be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Use this class `navbar-fixed-bottom` to fix it to bottom of the screen

`<footer class="page-footer navbar-fixed-bottom">`

Ok, In your case increasing the `padding-bottom: 115px` in the custom class `page-footer` works but you have to verify it in other devices.

```
.page-footer {
    padding-bottom: 115px; // Old value 90px
    .....
    ....
}
```

Comment: It almost fixed my problem, but I would like it not fixed (I don't want it stuck to the bottom as I scroll. I want it at the bottom when I scroll there)

If I change <footer class="page-footer navbar-fixed-bottom"> to <footer class="page-footer navbar-bottom">, the same problem occurs.

Comment: Still does not work correctly on 4K 2560px screens to be specific, but it does work on smaller screens. :(